# How can I get the character '\n' from input file?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, jagged-arrays

I am trying to get input data from a txt file on Linux / Mint. So, after compiling the code I run the following command: ./a.out  output.txt
I need to fill a two-dimensional array but like a jagged array (the number of columns in each row is different).  So I want to split it by looking character what is read from file. If the character is '\ n', I want to fill the second line. But I guess I can not read the '\ n' character. I hope I can explain the problem.
I'm writing the code, maybe it will be more clearer.

my input.txt file is:

[image]

my c++ code part is for getting input:

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    int j = 0;
    while (ch != '\n') {
        arr[i][j] = ch;
        cin >> ch;
        j++;
    }
}
```

I want to that, if the character is equals the '\n' then program goes on to fill the array to next row.

```
arr[0][0] = 'a';
arr[0][1] = 'f'
arr[0][2] = 'h'

arr[1][0] = 'b'
arr[1][1] = 'e'
arr[1][2] = 'g'

arr[2][0] = 'c' .......)
```

Comment: [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) reads until the end of a line

Comment: Not too clear what you want, but why not use std::get().

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use `std::ifstream` to input text files, instead of `std::cin`. As it was commented before, `getline` is a good choice to read the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `cin >> ch` it will skip whitespace, which includes spaces, tabs and newline characters. Perhaps, you need to read entire lines using [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and then process each line separately.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    std::string line;
    int ln = 0;
    while (getline(cin, line)) // read entire line
    {
        istringstream is;
        is.str(line);
        while (is >> ch) // now read individual chars from that line
            cout << "line: " << ln << " char: " << ch << endl;
        ln++;
    }
}
```

And your loop should be something like this:

```
std::string line;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
    char ch;
    if (!std::getline(cin, line))
        break;
    std::istringstream is;
    is.str(line);
    for (int j=0; is >> ch; ++j)
        arr[i][j] = ch;
}
```

You omitted details on how you declare your `arr`, but it doesn't seem like the code you've shown would handle it properly. Perhaps, it would be better to use vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > arr;
std::string line;
char ch;
while (std::getline(cin, line)) // cin should probably be replaced with ifstream
{
    std::istringstream is;
    is.str(line);
    arr.push_back(vector<char>());
    for (int j=0; is >> ch; ++j)
        arr.back().push_back(ch);
}
```